# What is the best privacy hedge for the US northeast?

Tags: plant-recommendations, hedge, privacy-plants

I am looking for a privacy hedge which is dense, grows to at least 6 ft tall, has small leaves and is evergreen and can sustain harsh winter of northeast USA.

I like boxwood "Green Velvet" for its leaf size and color but it doesn't grow that tall and growth is slow as well.

I see a lot of hedge videos on YouTube from Australia but not as much in the USA.

I really like Moonshadow Euonymus which has awesome leaves but it doesn't grow tall and have not seen any pictures showing as hedge.

Answer (score 4):

Leyland Cypress is a popular privacy tree on the west coast, and will also grow well on the east coast from what I have heard. It can be planted as a dense hedge, and provides year round color. They are very hardy, and with fertilizer/good soil can grow 3 feet a year. They will get quite tall if you don't keep them under control, but they accept pruning well, and can be kept manageable. The only thing I've ever seen kill a Leyland is being girdled.

[image: Manicured as a hedge]
Manicured as a hedge
[image: More natural shape]
More natural shape

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered some of the varieties of *[privet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privet)*?

This is used extensively in the Northeast US as a hedge along property lines, especially *[Ligustrum ovalifolium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligustrum_ovalifolium)*, and grows up to 15 ft. high.

[image: privet]

It is often sheared to achieve flat or rounded sides and tops.

Comment: The golden privet is one on the short list but I don't think its truly evergreen and leaves are somewhat larger. I see videos of 'goodbye neighbor' which looks good but not sure if it suits north east?

Comment: Please don't plant privets. They're really bad for people with allergies and they're an invasive species. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privet_as_an_invasive_plant